# eclipse scout neon : Texts in extended project

Tags: localization, translation, eclipse-scout, eclipse-neon

I have extended project in eclipse scout neon, and I would like to know how to enable texts it this project.

I copy Texts.nls file and create texts folder with Texts.properties inside. 
Auto create texts from code doesn't work and give me an error :

```
The NLS Project is read-only. heck that you have a valid NLS Project in your workspace.
```

If I add text manually in texts.properties file, it doesn't read from it. 
How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your `Texts.nls` file correctly? Here an example:

```
###############################################
# This file is maintained by the NLS editor.  #
# To ensure a properly working NLS support    #
# keep this file untouched.                   #
###############################################
Nls-Class=org.eclipse.scout.contacts.shared.TextProviderService
```

The corresponding `TextProviderService` java class:

```
package org.eclipse.scout.contacts.shared;

import org.eclipse.scout.rt.platform.Order;
import org.eclipse.scout.rt.shared.services.common.text.AbstractDynamicNlsTextProviderService;

@Order(2000)
public class TextProviderService extends AbstractDynamicNlsTextProviderService {
  @Override
  protected String getDynamicNlsBaseName() {
    return "org.eclipse.scout.contacts.shared.texts.Texts";
  }
}
```

This is the way how the Scout SDK lookup for your properties files.